# Django and JQuery Issue

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django

Hopefully someone can point me in the right direction here.  I've wrote the following JQuery, which successfully submits the request to DJango View and then returns information, however it doesn't appear to enter the success: function.  I'm trying to see Success appear in the console.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

View Response

```
return JsonResponse({'success': False, 'message':'There was an incorrect "Action" Value. Speak to your systems administrator.'})
```

JQuery

```
$('.deletesubbutton').click(function(){
    var sub_menu_id, the_body;
    sub_menu_id = $(this).attr("data_sub_menu_id");
    elid = "#DELsubmenuModalBody" + sub_menu_id;
    the_body = $(elid);
    $.ajax({
        url: '/pages/ajax_request/submenu/', 
        type: 'POST',
        data: {id: sub_menu_id, action: "delee"}, 
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function(data){
            the_body.append("Boo");
            console.log("Success");
        },
        fail: function(data){
            console.log("Fail");
        }
    });
});
```

View Function

## admin view function to manage records

```
@login_required(login_url='/auth/login/')
def ajax_request(request, dataset):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if dataset in ['submenu', 'menu'] and request.is_ajax():
            # ensure the action paramter is set
            if 'action' in request.POST:
                #ipdb.set_trace()
                # this section is for the delete action
                if request.POST['action'] == 'delete':
                    # test if the required parameters are not included
                    # check required paramters are included in the post request
                    if 'id' not in request.POST:
                        return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'success': False, 'message':'There was an error processing the request.  Required parameter values missing.'}), content_type="application/json")
                    else:
                        # include try clause to capture errors caused by non-integer parameters being submitted.
                        try:
                            menu_id = int(request.POST['id'])
                        except:
                            return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'success': False, 'message':'There was an error processing the request. Invalid parameter type detected.'}), content_type="application/json")
                        if dataset == 'menu':
                            queryset = Menu.objects.get(id=menu_id)
                        elif dataset == 'submenu':
                            queryset = Sub_Menu.objects.get(id=menu_id)
                            sub_menu_id = queryset.menu
                        else:
                            return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'success': False, 'message':'There was an error processing the request.  Incorrect level value.'}), content_type="application/json")
                    try:
                        queryset.delete()
                        if dataset == 'menu':
                            renum_menu_items()
                        else:
                            renum_menu_items(sub_menu_id)
                        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('manage_admin_form', kwargs={'dataset': 'menu'}))
                    except:
                        return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'success': False, 'message':'There was an error deleting the menu item. Speak to your systems administrator.'}), content_type="application/json")
                else:
                    return JsonResponse({'success': False, 'message':'There was an incorrect "Action" Value. Speak to your systems administrator.'})
            else:
                return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'success': False, 'message':'There was an error processing the request.  Required parameter values missing.'}), content_type="application/json")
        else:
            return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'success': False, 'message':'There was an error processing the request.  Required parameter values missing.'}), content_type="application/json")
    else:
        if dataset == 'submenu':
            return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'message': 'Returns a message', 'submenu_id': 'Returns the Sub Menu ID'}), content_type="application/json")
        elif dataset == 'menu':
            return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'message': 'Returns a message', 'menu_id': 'Returns the Menu ID'}), content_type="application/json")
        else:
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('pages'))
```

It may not be the best code, but I'm only learning ;-)

Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: dataType: 'json', instead dataType: 'jsonp',

Comment: Yes, you should show the rest of the view.

Comment: could you post the function in your `views.py` ?

Comment: Added the view as requested :)

Comment: Typo is to test the exception to stop me deleting and recreating data to test the function with ;-)

Comment: @rizotas, that fixed it.  Cannot remember why I added p at the end but that was a tweak I made when I was trying to get something else work.